# Experimenting Functions

Tags: python, function, newline

```
name="D. Perkins  "
age="69"
ethnicity="black"
print(name,"\n",age,ethnicity)
```

Im new and experimenting with functions in python, this one in particular results in:

```
D. Perkins   
 69 black
^
```

this gap here is what I'm trying to solve, how would I do this ? Particularly in one string. Is there a better way to start a new line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sep="\n"` in print function,

```
print(name, age+ethnicity, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use string interpolation here in numerous ways, e.g. if you are using Python 3.6 or newer

```
name="D. Perkins  "
age="69"
ethnicity="black"
print(f"{name}\n{age} {ethnicity}")
```

or using string formatting

```
print("{n}\n{a} {e}".format(n=name, a=age, e=ethnicity))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an extra space there, is because the [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function inserts a separator between each argument.  Because you did not specify a separator, a space is used.

```
print(name,"\n",age,ethnicity)
```

results as:

```
name + " " + "\n" + " " + age + " " + ethnicity
```

That space after the newline is your problem.

For you to get a new line without a leading space on the next line, concatenate your string outside of the print function like so:

```
lines = name + "\n" + age + " " + ethnicity
print(lines)
```

Python takes a little getting used to.  Once you learn the basics, it is a very powerful language.